# Find a single record in a nested array by ID and sort based on another nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the object below in MongoDB and my back end is using nodeJS. to retrieve the data from DB. both  `"_id": "idq2"` and `"_id": "id1"` are given to us in the API body.

```
questions = [
    {
        "_id": "idq1"
        "questiontext": "some question",
        "author": "auth2",
        "Answers": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "idq2"
        "questiontext": "some question",
        "author": "auth1",
        "Answers": [
            {
                "_id": "id1",
                "author": "auth1",
                "comments" [
                    {
                        "author": "auth1",
                        "comment": "some comments",
                        "rate": 1,
                        "_id": "idc1"
                    }
                    , {
                        "comment": "some comments",
                        "_id": "idc2"
                        "rate": 3
                    }
                    , {
                        "comment": "some comments",
                        "_id": "idc3"
                        "rate": 2
                    }
                    , {
                        "comment": "some comments",
                        "_id": "idc4",
                        "rate": 5
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                "_id": "id2",
                "author": "auth2",
                "comments" []
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Assume I have the  "_id": "idq2" and "_id": "id1", I am trying to get the object below.

**Expected result :**

```
Answer = {
    "_id": "id1",
    "author": "auth1",
    "comments" [
        {
            "author": "auth1",
            "comment": "some comments",
            "rate": 1,
            "_id": "idc1"
        },
        {
            "comment": "some comments",
            "_id": "idc3"
            "rate": 2
        }
        , {
            "comment": "some comments",
            "_id": "idc2"
            "rate": 3
        }

    ]
}
```

To make it a simple question: How to get a single "Answers" object with the "id1" and first 3 comments sorted by the rate parameter in the ascending order, the object should be a single object.

Comment: So you've two docs in collection `"_id": "idq1"` & `"_id": "idq2"` what is the filter to get `"_id": "id1",
    "author": "auth1"` ?

Comment: I am getting the id from an API body, so we can assume we have these two ids

Comment: So you mean to say `"_id": "idq2"` & Answers array id :: `"_id": "id1"` ? But how come your question says  `"_id": "idq1"` ?

Comment: Yup we have those two id's, I edit the question to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) for this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Filter docs with required criteria */
    {
      $match: { "_id": "idq2", "Answers._id": "id1" }
    },
    /** get only one needed element from `Answers` array & now `Answers` will be an object */
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        Answers: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$Answers", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "id1" ] } } }, 0 ] }
      }
    },
    /** Unwind `comments` array to do sorting */
    {
      $unwind: "$Answers.comments"
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        "Answers.comments.rate": 1
      }
    },
    /** group back based on `Answers._id` & push comments back to `comments` array */
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$Answers._id",
        author: { $first: "$Answers.author" },
        comments: { $push: "$Answers.comments" }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/678ljhivZLb)

**Note :** This query will either return an empty array `[]` if none of the docs match with `$match` criteria or else will return an array of one object in the response. Remember `.aggregate()` will always return an array.